# Intellisense not working with templates VS2012 ultimate c++

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, intellisense

Intellisense is working very badly with my VS...

When I'm coding in C++ it works 100% fine, until I start using templates, then it just stops working completely, stops detecting errors and don't auto-complete in all cases.

I'm inclined to believe it has to do with something I have done with my code that broke it.

So I started by creating a class with a struct in it:

```
template<typename T>
class List<T>
{
private:
    struct Node
    {
        T value;
        Node* next;
        Node* previous;
    };
    Node* First;
    Node* Last;
...
};
```

later, I declare some additional functions:

```
template<typename T>
inline T List::First()
{
    return First;
}
```

so far so good, intellisense is working 100% fine, but if I try to do first-> it won't work, VS won't tell give me any options (ctrl + space doesn't work).

also, if I type some nonsense it won't tell me it's wrong:

```
sdkjgisjdga->vsrsiib = 123jgi;
```

I don't really know what to do in order to fix this.

Thank you for your time and efforts.

PS: I already tried to reset the configurations.

EDIT: Forgot to say that if i don't use templates in my .h file then intellisense works correctly.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Templates need to be instantiated before you can definitively say what they contain. For example, your `First->` snippet points to a `List<T>::Node`, and that is obviously dependent on the exact `T`.

Sure, Intellisense in this simple case could unambiguously list the members by just substituting `T==int` for a moment. But consider what's worse: Intellisense not knowing the members (like now) or Intellisense mis-guessing in the hard cases where you need it most?

Comment: Ok, so it is working as inteded and wasn't me who did something wrong =) ty for the answer. I'll just have to get used to it.

Answer (score 9):

I am a bit late with this answer, and maybe the OP is not working on this code anymore, but I think this may still help someone who is searching templates and IntelliSense.

One thing you can try -- if you want to be able to see your typos and errors as you type, but if you want your code to be template-able -- is using an #if-#else-#endif:

```
#if MY_USE_TEMPLATES 
template <typename T> 
#else 
typedef [**your-test-type-here**] T; 
#endif 
class List { 
... your code here ... 
}
```

In Visual Studio 2015 this seems to work. You can define MY_USE_TEMPLATES to be 0 (using a #define), develop your code with IntelliSense and auto-complete, etc. (so you make less mistakes), and then change the MY_USE_TEMPLATES to 1 when you are ready to test or compile with actual template code.

While you have MY_USE_TEMPLATES turned on, code that references your List will result in error (i.e., code like 'List myList'), and you can resolve that with an extra dummy 'template' inside the #else statement. However, the good thing about leaving the #else clause without an extra 'template' is: the error you get when referencing your List may serve you as a reminder to turn on MY_USE_TEMPLATES before testing the code, reducing the probability of a bug. (Experience suggests that it is easy to forget when handling a lot of things and large projects ...)

Do be careful about using multiple such type definitions, however: the 'typedef ... T' can only be safely used once for that name "T"; while you can use 'typedef ... TYPE1' for one class and 'typedef ... TYPE2' for another, you *cannot* safely use the same type name for different types unless you put the different type names into separate namespaces. (I tried this in Visual Studio 2015.)