# Visual studio doesn't underline errors when using a template (template<typename T>)

Tags: c++, visual-studio, templates

When I use a template with template for example before my class, It will not underline my errors in red and I need to try to compile for it to point them out. If I do not use a template it works fine. Any ideas?

Visual Studio 2015 Community C++

Comment: Related? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13274992/intellisense-not-working-with-templates-vs2012-ultimate-c

Comment: Also make a reproducible example ...

Comment: Unless you are using a commercial tool such as ReSharper for C++, some syntax cannot be properly parsed by VS. You might report to Microsoft Connect.